# Random coloring of a graph with $c^2$ edges using c colors

Tags: combinatorics, random-graphs

Suppose that $|| ≤ ^2$ for some fixed $ ∈ N$. Prove that it is possible to assign a
color to each vertex of  so that at most 2 different colors are used in total and
for each edge, its end vertices have different colors.

First, I need to consider a random coloring using only c colors but I am not sure how to continue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a random colouring using $c$ colours.  For each edge, the probability that both vertices are the same colour is $1/c$.  The expected number of monochromatic edges is then $\le c^2/c = c$.  The probability that there are at most $c$ monochromatic edges is nonzero, so there exist colourings with $c$ colours that have at most $c$ monochromatic edges.  Now take such a colouring, and using each of the remaining $c$ colours at most once, recolour one vertex of each monochromatic edge.